# xfce Display settings does not run - RandR issue

Tags: display, xfce, settings

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 with XFCE, in a virtual machine (accessing it remotely). I need to update the screen/resolution/display/appearance.

If I go to *Application* → *Settings* → *Appearance*, a window is displayed and disappears right away.

If I try *Application* → *Settings* → *Display*, I get the following error:

[image: error]

I searched here and the net, but I can't really find a solution.

Comment: Just an FYI:  The current Ubuntu 16.04.6 system is .6, not .1 - so check you have all your updates. Also Xubuntu/XFCE, along with all other flavors excluding Kylin are EOL & thus unsupported. Only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with Unity 7), Server (no desktop) or Kylin are still supported.  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/  (5 years from 2016-April for Ubuntu, 3 years for flavors excluding Kylin [16.04 only])

Comment: OK, thanks for the details. I use xfce as I have understood is the only desktop app that allows remoting through RDP from a win machine. I do an update but getting start error as I indicated in another thread here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195141/unable-to-connect-to-upstart-failed-to-connect-to-socket-com-ubuntu-upstart-co

Comment: Correct, Sorry, my bad, I have just issued lsb_release -a, I have Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS codename : xenial