# unable to connect to Upstart Failed to connect to socket com/ubuntu/upstart : connection refused

Tags: upstart

I have a Ubuntu 16, whenever I run an apt-get update, things go correctly then I get a message indicating

```
Processing triggers......
start: unable to connect to Upstart Failed to connect to socket com/ubuntu/upstart : connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure)
subprocess installed post-installation script returned exit status 1
....
...
Package runit is not configured yet
```

What is strange, I ran
apt-get install nodejs, I got the same error but node setup finished correctly and was able to run node.

Why I am getting this upstart message? I understood in this forum that this is a deprecated feature since Ubuntu 15. How I can get rif of it?

Comment: Ubuntu 16?   Is this an IoT device or appliance running Ubuntu Core 16? however there was non Ubuntu Core 15?  Standard Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, with only special purpose releases given the *year* format.  It's better if you're specific with your detail. Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` (apt-get -f install equally good). If it asks you to run a `dpkg-reconfigure` I would do that too and note any messages in those commands.

Comment: Any chance you have some from git on your system like git-all or git-daemon-run? `dpkg -l | grep git`

Comment: Sorry, it is 16.04.6 LTS codename : xenial. Yes I have git-daemon-run I will check and come back with more details

Comment: is upstart also on your System? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284249/why-this-error-about-upstart-systemd-with-runit

Comment: nobody, not sure what I should do following this thread you pointed me to? it talks about an not ideal fix, as I am not expert, I don't want to play with this

Answer (score 0):

When I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` it works getting packages, unpacking .... as follows but it ends with the message

```
Errors were encountered while processing:  runit  git-daemon-run E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  containerd.io snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  docker-ce kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-ftp erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools
  erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tftp erlang-tools erlang-xmerl git git-all
  git-arch git-cvs git-daemon-run git-doc git-el git-email git-gui git-mediawiki git-svn gitk gitweb libpcap0.8 libpulse-mainloop-glib0
  libpulse0 libpulsedsp libsmbclient libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libwbclient0 pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils samba-libs
43 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 17,9 MB/28,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 465 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I respond by Yes, a lot of packages got prepared and installed but still

```
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio-utils_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb
 ... Unpacking pulseaudio-utils (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.11) over
 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10) ... Preparing to unpack
 .../pulseaudio-module-x11_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
 pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.11) over (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10) ...
 Preparing to unpack
 .../pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.11) over
 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10) ... Preparing to unpack
 .../pulseaudio_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb ... Unpacking pulseaudio
 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.11) over (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10) ... Preparing to unpack
 .../libpulse-mainloop-glib0_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.11) over
 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10) ... Preparing to unpack
 .../libpulse0_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
 libpulse0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.11) over (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10) ...
 Preparing to unpack .../libssh-4_0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking libssh-4:amd64 (0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5) over
 (0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.2) ... Preparing to unpack
 .../libssh-gcrypt-4_0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
 libssh-gcrypt-4:amd64 (0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5) over (0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.2)
 ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ... Processing triggers
 for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ... /sbin/ldconfig.real:
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 is not a symbolic link

 Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ... Processing 13 changed
 doc-base files... Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.5) ...
 Setting up git (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.7) ... Setting up git-svn
 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.7) ... Setting up git-el (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.7) ...
 Install git for emacs Install git for emacs24 install/git: Handling
 install of emacsen flavor emacs24 install/git: Byte-compiling for
 emacs24
 + emacs24 -batch -q -no-site-file -f batch-byte-compile git.el git-blame.el Wrote /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/git/git.elc Wrote
 /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/git/git-blame.elc Setting up runit
 (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ... start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to
 connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused dpkg: error
 processing package runit (--configure):  subprocess installed
 post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency
 problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:  git-daemon-run
 depends on runit; however:   Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Setting up gitweb (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.7) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a         followup error from a previous failure.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt -f install
```

same thing.

Again, I installed openssh, everything went OK except at the end I got the same message

Thnaks